# entity recognize,just a word,not a whole sentence to reognize,what should use Algorithm about NLP

Tags: algorithm, nlp

when i input a parameter "marry" into function,then,return "this is name",when i input a parameter "MIT",then,return "this is institution name",just a word,not a whole sentence to reognize,what should use Algorithm about NLP? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like part-of-speech tagging and/or named entity recognition BUT if you are processing English, single words without context are potentially ambiguous. Also, single words may not be informative. "new" on it's own can be an adjective (POS) but "New York" is most likely a location (NER). Check some literature on both tasks and consider processing at least sentence-level features.